# Python numpy reshape from (n,) to (n, 1 , 1)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array defined like the following:

```
array([ 0.1394957,  0.16518061,  0.15289813,  0.14116833 ])
```

and I would like to reshape to something like:

```
array([[[0.1394957 ]],

   [[0.16518061]],

   [[0.15289813]],

   [[0.14116833]]])
```

The starting shape is `(n,)` and I would like to get `(n, 1, 1)`

I tried the following approach:

`newarr = arr.reshape(len(arr), 1, -1)` Is there another way?

Comment: `a[:, None, None]`

Comment: thanks, could you explain the reasoning? and how that differentiate from my approach?

Comment: `arr.reshape(-1,1,1)`